# Can not move QGraphicsScene object using addRect function

Tags: qt

Hi I am trying a very simple QGraghicsScene code in QT. But the addRect function is not working, as I try to add it to specific coordinate. It is always at the centre. I also have tried with setPos. But same result.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui -> setupUi(this);

        scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        ui -> graphicsView -> setScene(scene);
        QBrush greenBrush(Qt::green);
        QBrush blueBrush(Qt::gray);
        QPen outlinePen(Qt::black);
        outlinePen.setWidth(2);
        scene -> update();
        rectangle = scene -> addRect(20,200,100,100,outlinePen,greenBrush);
        scene - >update();
    }


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: I think it works fine. But as you only have a single object in the scene, the view centers autimatically to it.
For example, you can use this command "ui->graphicsView->fitInView(QRect(0,0,1920,1080));" for a full-hd sized scene.

Comment: setSceneRect to something say setSceneRect(0,0,500,500) , you can view your rect.